# I want to use the regex_replace only for the first character (phone number)

Tags: php, smarty, regexp-replace

I want to use the **regex_replace** or **regexp_extract** only for the first character (phone number).

For example:

> **8**9265558855 should replace **+7**9265558855

**replace only if first 8 on +7**

if I use {$phone|regex_replace:"/8/":"+7"}
I have For example:

> 89265558855 after replace I have +7926555+7+755

replace all 8 numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [start of string anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` to match only the first character like so:

```
{$phone|regex_replace:"/^8/":"+7"}
```